# Attempting to implement find in avl tree

Tags: c++, avl-tree

I'm using this code https://rosettacode.org/wiki/AVL_tree#C.2B.2B as a basis for an AVL tree. By default the example uses integers however I need to store strings. So I modified the code to debug mainly making the root public and trying to print the values.

```
22 /* AVL tree */
 23 template <class T>
 24 class AVLtree {
 25         public:
 26                 AVLtree(void);
 27                 ~AVLtree(void);
 28                 bool insert(T key);
 29                 void deleteKey(const T key);
 30                 void printBalance();
 31                 AVLnode<T> *root;
 32 
 33         private:
 34 
 35                 AVLnode<T>* rotateLeft          ( AVLnode<T> *a );
 36                 AVLnode<T>* rotateRight         ( AVLnode<T> *a );
 37                 AVLnode<T>* rotateLeftThenRight ( AVLnode<T> *n );
 38                 AVLnode<T>* rotateRightThenLeft ( AVLnode<T> *n );
 39                 void rebalance                  ( AVLnode<T> *n );
 40                 int height                      ( AVLnode<T> *n );
 41                 void setBalance                 ( AVLnode<T> *n );
 42                 void printBalance               ( AVLnode<T> *n );
 43                 void clearNode                  ( AVLnode<T> *n );
 44 };
..................................
247 int main(void)
248 {
249         AVLtree<std::string> t;
250 
251         std::cout << "Inserting integer values 1 to 10" << std::endl;
252         for (int i = 1; i <= 10; ++i)
253                 t.insert(i+" ");
254 
255         std::cout << "Printing balance: ";
256         t.printBalance();
257         std::cout << t.root->key + "\n";
258         std::cout << t.root->left->key + "\n";
259         std::cout << t.root->left->right->key + "\n";
260         std::cout << t.root->key;
261 
262 }
```

however the problem is that the result that prints out is

```
Inserting integer values 1 to 10
Printing balance: 1 0 -1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 
ing balance: 
Printing balance: 
g balance: 
ing balance:
```

And I have no idea why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are inserting junky strings into your data structure in these lines:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; ++i)
    t.insert(i+" ");
```

The type of `" "` is `const char *`, and when you add an integer to it, you get another `const char *` that is offset from the original pointer.  Because the string `" "` happened to be stored right before the string `"Printing balance:"` in your program, you ended up generating pointers to various positions inside of the `"Printing balance:"` string when you executed that code.

To properly convert numbers to strings in C++, you could use [std::to_string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string).

Comment: Thanks I was getting an error using to_string but decided to focus of fixing that instead of getting around it.